# USB3.0 or Type-C Portable Monitors with MacBook Pro 13" (Mid-2012)

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm looking at getting a portable monitor for use with my MacBook Pro 13" (Mid-2012, Core i7).

I'm thinking probably an Asus model MB169C+ or B+ at the moment. I know my MBP has USB3.0 and so the B+ should work fine. The MBP has a Thunderbolt port, which I believe is 1st Generation (10Gbps) - someone more familiar with Thunderbolt/mini-displayport might know if I'm wrong on this.

Which leads me to my question:

If I was to get the C+ model with USB type C, can first gen thunderbolt be converted and power the monitor correctly? Is there any reason not to just go with USB3.0?

Budget doesn't matter as it is to be purchased from an approved supplier and these are the only options.

Comment: Needs some fixups to not get rejected - you need to focus on the hardware recommendations over whether X would work. Tbolt 3 is compatible with USB C tho. TBolt2 uses a mini DP port

Comment: Done the necessary edits to improve its chances or survival on hardware recs. Feel free to do any additional changes - especially if you feel my edits stripped out necessary information. Checking what flavour of TB and what budget you have would help

Comment: Ok great thanks for that. I'll edit the post accordingly